# I am trying to deploy an app to heroku from Git bash, but I'm unable to open app in heroku

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app from **git-bash** to **heroku**, but I can't open the app in heroku. When I run the following command to install **npm**, I get an error.

```
npm install
```

Error code notification is available below:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine 
{ npm WARN EBADENGINE package: 'brandon-dorsey-portfolio@0.3.0', 
  npm WARN EBADENGINE required: { node: '^8.1.4' }, 
  npm WARN EBADENGINE current: { node: 'v16.13.1', npm: '8.1.4' } 
  npm WARN EBADENGINE
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Git Bash.If you want to deploy an app to heroku you have 3 ways to do it.
1.Use Github repo.
2.Use Heroku CLI.
3.Use Docker Container.

Comment: After using Heroku CLI I am still getting the same message. Any additional advice?